# A problem changing to spherical coordinates: $\iiint f = 0$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

It seems I still don't get how to determine the limits of the change of variables, the following excercise that I "invented" consists in using spherical coordinates to calculate an easy integral like $f(x,y,z) = c$ with $c\in\mathbb{R}$.
The problem arises if I define a set $D=\{(x,y,z):0\leq\alpha \leq x^2+y^2+z^2\leq\beta\}$ as a domain in order to have a sphere with the "core" -this is, substracting the inside sphere with radius $\sqrt{\alpha}$-.

To describe the sphere with spherical coordinates I would use $x=\rho\sin\psi\cos\theta, y=\rho\sin\sin\theta,z=\rho\cos\theta$ with $\sqrt{a}\leq r\leq \beta,  0\leq\psi\leq\pi, 0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi$. I could calculate $f$ without problems, but what would happen if I change $c$ by $z$?.

The problem here is that $\displaystyle\iiint_Dz = \displaystyle\int_{\sqrt{a}}^{\sqrt{b}}\rho^3\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi} \sin\psi\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}\cos\theta\;d\theta d\psi dr = 0$ because $\displaystyle\int_0^ {2\pi}\cos \theta\; d\theta=\sin\theta|_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi} =0$.

This seems strange, I guess that could be zero because $f$ would be taking negative values in the bottom half of the "spheric form" and the same values but positive in the upper half?.

Also, is there a name for the sets like $D$?

Comment: Where is Jacobian?

Comment: It was the $\rho^2\cos\psi$ which was wrong. I just changed it to $\rho^2\sin\psi$. Thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets like $D$ as spherical shells. Consider the case where $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = 4$. Then what you have is the region between spheres of radius $1$ and $2$. Since you said $\alpha \ge 0$ then it can also be a solid sphere.

What you computed by switching to $z$ was the first moment with respect to the plane $xy$. Since you are integrating over something symmetrical about it (a spherical shell), the answer is zero. If you had chosen $z^2$ it wouldn't be.

Another way I just thought of conceiving this: consider you are calculating the volume charge whose density is given by the distance to the plane $xy$ (in other words, $f(x,y,z) = z$). For $z \ge 0$ you have a positive charge, while for $z<0$ you have a negative charge. Since the volume is the same, the net charge for the body must be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Your integral is obviously zero because the symmetries of the domain and the integrand. Try cov theorem with the transformation $z\rightarrow -z$.